# polymer 1.0 event firing among nested components

Tags: events, polymer, listener, polymer-1.0

I have a problem in Polymer 1.0 related to event propagation within a nested structure of web components. In particular, I am trying to dynamically configure a web component named `wc-split` by means of a collection of other components named `wc-split-rule` located within its local DOM. The following snippet of code shows a correct form of use:

```
<wc-split-test>
    <wc-split>
        <wc-split-rule key="{{k1}}" ...></wc-split-rule>
        <wc-split-rule key="{{k2}}" ...></wc-split-rule>
        <wc-split-rule key="{{k3}}" ...></wc-split-rule>
   </wc-split> 
</wc-split-test>
```

As it can be seen in the previous example, the aim is to provide to the `wc-split` component the values on `key` attributes within each `wc-split-rule` component. As we need dynamic reconfiguration capabilities, the architectural strategy starts by firing an event each time a change in `key` attributes is met and those changes are promoted by bubbling up to reach the `wc-split` component, which process them.

The followed approach works properly when [1] it is both tested in a pure HTML context with literal values and [2] within a component template with data-bound values. Nevertheless, [3] when it is tested within a component template using literal values,  changes are not promoted. It seems that event propagation are ignored or listener defined in `wc-split` does not catch the event:

```
<wc-split-test>
    <wc-split> <!-- does not work -->
        <wc-split-rule key="k1" ...></wc-split-rule>
        <wc-split-rule key="k2" ...></wc-split-rule>
        <wc-split-rule key="k3" ...></wc-split-rule>
    </wc-split>
</wc-split-test>
```

The following listing shows implementation of both components [https://goo.gl/OkU9jQ]:

```
    <dom-module id="wc-split-rule">
        <script>                
            Polymer({
                is: 'wc-split-rule',  

                properties: {
                    key  : {
                        type: String,
                        reflectToAttribute: true,
                        notify: true,
                        value: '',
                        observer: '_changed'
                    },
                }, 

                _changed: function (){
                    this.fire('wc-split-rule', {
                        key     : this.key,
                    });                        
                }    

            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>


    <dom-module id="wc-split">   
        <template>
           <content></content>         
        </template>

        <script>     
            Polymer( { 
                is: 'wc-split', 

                listeners: {
                    'wc-split-rule': 'onRule'
                },

                ready: function(){
                   ...
                },

                onRule: function (event, context){
                    ... // this is executed in test [1] and [2] NOT in [3]                        
                }
            });     
        </script>

    </dom-module>


    <dom-module id="wc-split-test">          
        <template>              
            <wc-split id="split">
                <wc-split-rule key="e1"/>                        
            </wc-split>            
        </template>

        <script>     
            ...
        </script>

    </dom-module>
```

Surprisingly, the same code on Polymer 0.5 works properly for each test scenario [https://goo.gl/CHV3JE]:

```
    <polymer-element name="wc-split-rule">  
        <script>

            Polymer('wc-split-rule', {
                publish : {
                    key     : '',                       
                },

                observe: {
                    key     : '_changed',                       
                },

                _changed: function (){
                    this.fire('wc-split-rule', {
                        key     : this.key,
                    });                        
                }    

            });
        </script>
    </polymer-element>


    <polymer-element name="wc-split">
        <template>
            <div on-wc-split-rule="{{onRule}}">
                <content select="wc-split-rule"></content>
            </div>
            <content></content>        
        </template>
        <script>

            Polymer('wc-split', {                    

                ready: function(){
                    ...
                },                   

                onRule: function (event, context){
                    ... // this is always executed
                }
            });     
        </script>

    </polymer-element>


     <polymer-element name="wc-split-test">
        <template>              
            <wc-split id="split">
                <wc-split-rule key="e1"/>                        
            </wc-split>            
        </template>

        <script>
            ...
        </script>

    </polymer-element>
```

Comment: Running your sample, it appears that the parent is receiving an event. Can you clarify the problem? What do you expect the 1.0 sample to do that it isn't doing now?

Comment: Thanks DocDude for your help.  I have rewrite the question. Please, could you take a glance to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to a timing issue. The `wc-split-rule` event is firing before your `wc-split` element is registered. Therefore, the event is being missed. It's only an issue when the elements are first booted up b/c you have a parent element that's also a custom element. One way around this is to ensure the event fires after the `wc-split-rule` is attached:

```
attached: function() {
  this._changed();
},
```

This works: http://jsbin.com/yixinuhahu/edit?html,output